# How can I order a query result same as the id specified in the WHERE condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM test JOIN test2 ON test.id=test2.id
 WHERE test.id IN (562,553,572)
 GROUP BY test.id
```

Its results are ordered like this: 553, 562, 572...

But I need the same order that I specified in the `IN(562,553,572)` condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY FIELD(`test`.`id`, 562, 553, 572)
```

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY CASE test.id
 WHEN 562 THEN 0
 WHEN 553 THEN 1
 WHEN 572 THEN 2
 END`

Answer (score 2):

One way is like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM test JOIN test2 ON test.id=test2.id
 WHERE test.id IN (562,553,572)
 ORDER BY CASE test.id
          WHEN 562 THEN 1
          WHEN 553 THEN 2
          WHEN 572 THEN 3
          ELSE          4
          END;
```

You don't need GROUP BY unless you are computing aggregates.  The ELSE clause is superfluous here, but it is generally a good idea to include it.

Comment: How different is this from the `FIELD` function? SQL standards?

Comment: @Nirmal: yes - I don't know which DBMS support the FIELD function (but it certainly isn't all of them); OTOH, I don't know of a DBMS that does not support CASE.

Answer (score 2):

Could do something with FIND_IN_SET():

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
   JOIN test2 
   ON test.id = test2.id
  WHERE test.id IN (562,553,572)
  ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(test.id, '562,553,572');
```