# Order of "WHERE field IN" SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I am using the following SQL to select records from MySQL database:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_product WHERE id IN (3,22,1);
```

The results order equals "ORDER BY id ASC", so as in example records 1,3,22 are returned. How can I get them ordered in the exact way as typed in IN clause? So ordered as 3,22,1 ? Thank you.

Comment: Consider finding something else to order your records by. IDs should be allowed to be changing or non-static.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I order a query result same as the id specified in the WHERE condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984531/how-can-i-order-a-query-result-same-as-the-id-specified-in-the-where-condition)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numerous options -

### CASE:

Preferred, being ANSI-92 it's portable to other databases.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM cms_product 
   WHERE id IN (3,22,1)
ORDER BY CASE id
           WHEN 3 THEN 1
           WHEN 22 THEN 2
           WHEN 1 THEN 3
         END
```

### FIND_IN_SET:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM cms_product 
   WHERE id IN (3,22,1)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,22,1');
```

### FIELD:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM cms_product 
   WHERE id IN (3,22,1)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3, 22, 1);
```

Reference:

- [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)
- [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)
- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 6):

Try using `ORDER BY FIELD`, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_product WHERE id IN (3,22,1) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 3, 22, 1);
```

[source here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784)

Comment: Ooh, actual documentation. I don't remember stumbling across that in my readings, so thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be very neat, but you may want to do the following:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      cms_product 
WHERE     id IN (3, 22, 1)
ORDER BY  id = 3 DESC, id = 22 DESC, id = 1 DESC;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE cms_product (id int, value int);

INSERT INTO cms_product VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO cms_product VALUES (3, 200);
INSERT INTO cms_product VALUES (22, 300);
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    3 |   200 |
|   22 |   300 |
|    1 |   100 |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The `... ORDER BY FIELD (id, 3, 22, 1)` as suggested by [@Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011056/order-of-where-field-in-sql-query/4011073#4011073) and [@OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011056/order-of-where-field-in-sql-query/4011088#4011088) returns the same results, and is actually much neater.

Comment: Very doubtful that this would scale to a long IN list, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it has to be either ASC or DESC.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, '3', '22', '1') ???