# " where in " mysql clause

Tags: php, mysql

i used a mysql query where there is "where id in ("22,20,21") "
but when i get the result its like array ordered in asecending order ie  20,21,20

but i need it in the same order as i gave the clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I order a query result same as the id specified in the WHERE condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984531/how-can-i-order-a-query-result-same-as-the-id-specified-in-the-where-condition)

Comment: i'm agreeing with @deceze that it is a duplicate.  hadn't seen your answer or probably would've pointed him in that direction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i *think* you should be able to use the FIELD keyword like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id in (22,20,21)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,22,20,21);
```

this is mysql specific, and seems magical, but it works.

Comment: To explain some of the magic... What's happening here is that the FIELD function looks up `id` in the remaining parameters passed to it, and returns a number. So if id=22, FIELD(...) returns 0, and if id=20, it returns 1.

Comment: @Michal Kopinsky, i've never really found good documentation on this function.  care to share your source of magical knowledge? ;)

Comment: @nathan It's right here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: This isn't even what I'm looking for, but kudos on an awesome little tip.

Answer (score 2):

SQL results are unordered unless given an explicit ordering; the order won't be picked up from the `in` clause.

Since the IDs are neither ASC nor DESC either, you'd have to `ORDER BY` something else; how are you determining the 22,20,21 order in the first place?

Comment: select id,dets from details where id in(22,21,20,19)

Comment: i am taking that ids from other table which is a mapping table

Comment: this is actually not true in mysql.

Comment: @Anish Then you should fetch both together in a `JOIN` query and `ORDER BY mapping_table.the_order_id`.

Comment: For a MySQL-specific solution, see @nathan's answer below. For a general solution, like @deceze says, perhaps combine the two queries into one and order by the mapping table.

Comment: not like that.. i got ids from other table where i am storing the ids of the details . and using that array to avoid recursive calls to mysql i used where in clause

Comment: @Anish Not sure what you mean by "recursive calls". If you could describe your situation in more detail, I'm sure we could come up with an elegant query. Preemptive strike: Please update your question with any new information.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned... `WHERE` clause doesn't do anything with ordering of result set. Use [MySQL built-in `FIELD` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) in `ORDER BY` clause to specify how the result set should be ordered:

```
... WHERE id IN (22, 20, 21) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 22, 20, 21) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the order results will be returned in in a `WHERE` clause. If you want to specify order, you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query. For a solution that uses `FIND_IN_SET` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195642/avoid-sorting-by-the-mysql-in-keyword/4195717#4195717).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the database system returns the results in whatever order it feels like. If you want it to be ordered, you have to tell it. [This blog post](http://www.daltonfilho.com/2008/10/04/arbitrary-sql-order-by/) provides one method for doing so; you may be able to find other solutions online.