# Mysql count row /adding together 2 different result on 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php myAdmin
table name is productx and in it I have

```
---------------------------------------------
Id | gender | brand | category | subcategory|
---------------------------------------------
1  | women  | nike  | shoes    | sandalet   |
2  | women  | nike  | shoes    | nightshoes |
3  | women  | nike  | shoes    | sandalet   |
4  | women  | nike  | shoes    | nightshoes |
5  | women  | puma  | shoes    | sandalet   |
6  | women  | nike  | shoes    | eveningshoes|
7  | women  | puma  | shoes    | sandalet   |
8  | women  | nike  | shoes    | sandalet   |
```

than I have a form with checkboxes like this form submiting itself with javascript

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['shoes'])): ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="eveningshoes" value="<?php echo $eveningshoes; ?>"onclick="formSubmit()"<?php if(isset($_POST['eveningshoes'])):?>checked<?php endif;?>><?php echo $eveningshoes; antalSkor_subcategory_eveningshoes($shoes_post_var,$eveningshoes);?><br>
      <input type="checkbox"name="nightshoes" value="<?php echo $nightshoes; ?>"  onclick="formSubmit()"<?php if(isset($_POST['nightshoes'])):?>checked<?php endif;?>><?php echo $nightshoes; antalSkor_subcategory_nightshoes($shoes_post_var,$nightshoes);?><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sandalet" value="<?php echo $sandalet; ?>"onclick="formSubmit()"<?php if(isset($_POST['sandalet'])):?>checked<?php endif;?>><?php echo $sandalet; echo antalSkor_subcategory_sandalet($shoes_post_var,$sandalet);?><br>       
<?php endif;?>
```

if user clicks the checkbox with value sandalet 
gona output the result by using this function 
Function is the same for the other brand just want to hold it short here

```
function antalSkor_nike($shoes_post_var,$sandalet_post_var,$nightshoes_post_var,$eveningshoes_post_var,$nike) {
        if(isset($shoes_post_var) && isset($sandalet_post_var)){
        //if sandalet checked counting how many NIKE sandalet we have
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from productsx where category='$shoes_post_var ' AND subcategory='$sandalet_post_var' AND brand ='$nike'")or die (mysql_errno());
            $total1 = mysql_result($result1, 0);    
            echo ' '.'('.$total1.')';

        }elseif(isset($shoes_post_var) && isset($nightshoes_post_var)){     
        //if night shoes checked counting how many NIKE night shoes we have
            $result2=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from productsx where category='$shoes_post_var ' AND subcategory='$nightshoes_post_var' AND brand ='$nike'")or die (mysql_errno());
            $total2 = mysql_result($result2, 0);    
            echo ' '.'('.$total2.')';
        }elseif(isset($shoes_post_var) && isset($eveningshoes_post_var)){       
        //if evening shoes checked counting how many NIKE evening shoes we have
            $result3=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from productsx where category='$shoes_post_var ' AND subcategory='$$eveningshoes_post_var' AND brand ='$nike'")or die (mysql_errno());
            $total3 = mysql_result($result3, 0);    
            echo ' '.'('.$total3.')';
        }else{
        if(isset($shoes_post_var)){
                $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from productsx where category='$shoes_post_var ' AND brand ='$nike'")or die (mysql_errno());
            $total = mysql_result($result, 0);  
            echo ' '.'('.$total.')';
        }
    }
}
```

and result gona be

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="nike"value="<?php echo @$nike; ?>" onclick="formSubmit()"<?php    if(isset($_POST['nike'])):?>checked<?php endif;?>><?php echo @$nike; echo antalSkor_nike($shoes_post_var,$sandalet_post_var,$nightshoes_post_var,$eveningshoes_post_var,$nike);?><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="puma"value="<?php echo @$puma; ?>" onclick="formSubmit()"<?php    if(isset($_POST['puma'])):?>checked<?php endif;?>><?php echo @$puma; echo antalSkor_puma($shoes_post_var,$sandalet_post_var,$nightshoes_post_var,$eveningshoes_post_var,$puma);?><br>
```

Sandalet NIKE (3)
if user check only  nightshoes result gona be for nike
Nightshoes NIKE (2)

AND question is what if user checks both of them

how can I use query to count them to (5)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM productx WHERE ... WHEREs for brand, gender, and category ... AND subcategory IN ('sandalet', 'nightshoes')
```

Source: [WHERE IN MySQL Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311025/where-in-mysql-clause)

Comment: Thank you David your code is working :) sorry I cant vote yet, need to come up 15 reputation score.