# Formatting a PHP array for an SQL "IN" clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm attempting to query a database for records where the "product_id" is included in an array of products IDs.

The array is the post result of a multiple select input (`<select>`) and looks like:

```
$clients = 
  Array ( 
    [0] => 80000016-1302638679
    [1] => 8000003B-1329924004
  )
```

I would like to pass that array to the "IN" clause of an SQL statement such as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN (".$clients.")";
```

...but this doesn't work (Error: `Message: Array to string conversion`).

Several posts suggest using this function to format the array in a way suitable for SQL:

```
function format_array($array){
    return implode(', ', $array);
  }
}
```

Such as ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN (".format_array($clients).")";
```

That results in this query:

`SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN (80000016-1302638679, 8000003B-132992400)`

...and this error:

`Unknown column '8000003B' in 'where clause'`

**What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated! I can clarify the question if needed :)**

Comment: You need to put 80000016-1302638679 in quotation marks.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311025/where-in-mysql-clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is a better way

You mention in the comments that you are using CodeIgniter. Unless you are making something extraordinarily complicated, there is no practical reason you should be building your own home-baked queries when you have [`where_in`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) built in.

And if that doesn't work, then there is good ol' fashioned [`escape`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).

---

OK, so, you have most people saying that you need to quote the items and are giving you this:

```
function createInClause($arr)
{
    return '\'' . implode( '\', \'', $arr ) . '\'';
}
```

but that really isn't sufficient if you have the possibility for questionable input (such as [`'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --`](http://bobby-tables.com/). To protect against that, you need to make sure you check for [SQL injection:](http://bobby-tables.com/)

```
function createInClause($arr)
{
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($arr as $item)
    {
        // this line makes sure you don't risk a sql injection attack
        // $connection is your current connection
        $tmp[] = mysqli_escape_string($connection, $item);
    }
    return '\'' . implode( '\', \'', $tmp ) . '\'';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your thorough answer! 

When I use that function, however, I receive the following error: "mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters"

I'm using CodeIgniter, if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry about that. Forgot about the signature change.

Comment: Unfortunately CodeIgniter's `where_in` won't work for me since the query is rather complicated (sales reporting involving many cases based on user inputs).

Would you know if the `connection` variable for the `mysqli_escape_string` function is already present somewhere in CodeIgniter? I would rather not redefine the database connection, since I know CodeIgniter already handles that (although it might not readily have it available as a variable). I hope that makes sense!

Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate the great answer you provided!

Comment: @Andrew CI also has a workaround for that. Use `$this->db->escape`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this to put your ids in quotes:

```
function format_array($array){
    return "'" . implode("', '", $array) . "'";
  }
}
```

As cwallenpoole pointed out, you should escape the string if you haven't already. Not escaping a string is extremely dangerous, especially if you have a public application.

Comment: See comments below, for security against injection you need to use mysqli_escape_string().

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `80000016-1302638679` in quotation marks. Otherwise it assumes you are doing subtraction.

```
return "'".implode("', '", $array)."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function

```
function format_array($array){
    return implode("','", $array);
  }
}
```

And this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN ('".$clients."')";
```

Comment: This would wrap the entire where clause in one set of quotes, which won't work.

Comment: @garrettmurray Check the implode function also

if there are two items in $array=array(456456,4569845934);

format array will return 456456','4569845934

And then $sql will be

    SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN ('456456','4569845934')

Comment: My fault, for some reason I missed that bit. =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put those in quotation markes like

```
 SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN ('80000016-1302638679', '8000003B-132992400')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your items in quotes. Here's a quick fix:

```
$clientIds = "";
foreach ($clients as $client) {
  $clientIds .= ($clientIds == "" ? "" : ", ") . "'".mysqli_escape_string($client)."'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN (".$clientIds.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values under quote like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id IN ('80000016-1302638679', '8000003B-132992400')
```